# How to render a transparent object that reflects the hdri world?

Tags: rendering, transparency, hdri, world

I just can't render this animation. When I do, it turns out pink on a black background.

[image]

It's a transparent object that reflects the world background. Is there a possibility to render this or an another way to put a video/image inside of the transparent bubble? Here is the preview of the render.

I tried environmental texture nodes and did every output setting. I also don't have any missed files and packed everything into the blender file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: looks like your environment texture is not set up correctly. Check if there is an image (hdri) selected in your world shader nodes.

Comment: I second Timmethy - pink is the color of "texture not found" - check your image (environment) texture.